# Can I set ionic serve to not open a browser by default?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have multiple browser windows usually and it's always not popping up on the one I want.

Can I disable the feature of ionic serve opening in a browser?

Answer (score 64):

You can pass in the `--nobrowser` option, or simply `-b`:

```
ionic serve --nobrowser
```

Answer (score 29):

Old CLI: As @Claudiu mentioned `ionic server -b` will not start a browser.

New CLI: the new command is `ionic serve --no-open`.

If you want to start a browser but not the default one, you can use the `-w` option.

Eg if Chrome is your default browser, but you want `ionic serve` to use Firefox instead, you can do something like

`ionic serve -w "path/to/firefox.exe"` or just `ionic serve -w firefox` if Firefox is in the path.

More info on `ionic serve` options:

- http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/serve/
- `ionic serve --help`

Answer (score 8):

`ionic serve --no-open` is the new command. The no-browser has been deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can pass in the `package.json` in the :

```
"scripts": {
"clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
"build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
```

}

and pass in the `ionic:serve`.
like this: `"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve --nobrowser"`

and run in the terminal of your project the:
`npm run ionic:serve`

Comment: This really not a solution rather a complication, also, even using an updated version such as  `"ionic:serve": "ionic serve --no-open"` and `npm run ionic:serve`  it beahves weirdly and loops the command over and over again.